# node-soap createClient with certificates

Tags: node.js, web-services, ssl, soap, node-soap

I am trying to get a WSDL file through https using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

Here is my attempt:

```
ldap.getEmpowerments = function(uid) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var url = 'https://yradeowshabil.corp.leroymerlin.com/adeo-ws-habil/AccessManagementService?WSDL'

        createClient(url).then( function(client) {

            console.log(client.describe);

        }, function(error) {
            console.error('habilitation client failed', error);
        });
    });
};
```

That's giving me the output:

```
> hablitation client failed 
> [Error: 140274398734112:error:140773F2:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected
> message:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770: ]
```

I have two required certificates in order to establish a communiaction with the wsdl file.
I tried the setSecurity method but my client is never created so it's useless.

According to the documentation I can add some options in the createClient method and override the request object or httpClient. The thing is there is no explanation on how to do this. How can I do it and and [set up the my custom request with ssl](https://github.com/request/request#tlsssl-protocol)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi! I’m also struggling my way through node-soap right now, but I think I may be able to help. I’m less familiar with promises, but using a basic callback with `(err, client)` has worked for me (at least to create the client).

It also looks like you’re calling `createClient()` out of context? In my case I defined `var soap = require('soap'); ` then called `soap.createClient()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

I am using [Promise.denodeify()] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise#promisedenodeifyfn) to transform soap.createClient into a promise style function. ( var createClient = Promise.denodeify(soap.createClient)). 

The problem is not here, I succeeded using the client for other wsdl file. My problem is to reach a wsdl file in a server that require ssl certificates .

I am using plain xml request for now since I failed to instantiate the client wit node-soap.

Comment: Hmm—k. Above you’re saying that using `setSecurity()` doesn’t work because you can’t create a client. Did you redefine `createClient()` so it is accessible without referencing the `soap` object? As for SSL, I’m also stuck on that problem. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes createClient is a new function based on soap.createClient. The only difference is that it returns a promise, instead of requiring a callback parameter. You can see it like this: 
`function createClient(url) { return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) { soap.createClient(url, function(error, client) { reject(error); resolve(client); }})`

Comment: Ahh. TIL. Thanks! I was able to get an SSL request working, but I wasn’t using promises. In my case I had to explicitly pass the endpoint in again (`soap.createClient(url, {endpoint: url}, function(err, client){ ... }`) in the client constructor to allow https to be used. I can’t say I understand the format of your error, though, so I guess I’m no help. Sorry!

Comment: if you have found answer for this, could you please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try adding this to your app.js:

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately.